# ASP.NET MVC: Where does a DBContext class go?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

Im working on an MVC 5 project in ASP.NET and have just setup a local DB but im not to sure where the DB context class would fit in with the MVC structure

Comment: You can create a DataAccess folder and place `DbContext` class into it. You can also place `DbSet`m declarations and ModelBuilder statements to help you create tables.

Comment: Simply, it goes wherever you want it to go. There are no hard and fast rules. Only you can decide how to best layout your application.

Comment: Sure, you could just have it hanging out in your project root.  But if *everything* is chilling in there, that looks disorganized

Answer (score 4):

Typically I'd separate that out into a separate `Whatever.Data` project/layer, so that the solution structure would look something like:

[image]

The advantage of doing it this way, is that it lets you group together topics that only concern the Data layer. A typical data layer project might look like:

[image]

Going a little beyond what you had asked, I personally use the DbContext mainly in a repository, and I inject the repository into the controller with dependency injection.

Each repository method is a special-purpose domain behavior / business rule.

[image]

On the other hand, if you're exposing OData, then the ApiController does need the DbContext & Entity Framework et al.